# What is your biggest WPF gripe?

Tags: .net, wpf

Sorry for the subjective post but I thought this was a topic worth discussing.  With 4.0 WPF  finally became a pretty solid platform to develop rich applications with. However, there's some things that I still find quite limiting. With v.Next approaching it might be useful to highlight what your biggest WPF gripe is  (also don't forget to submit it to (http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions)

Here's my biggest gripes, what's yours ?

1) **Animation quality**. They could be smoother, don't get me wrong animations are nice but they're not of the quality you see with iOS  for instance. I'm not sure if this is because WPF doesn't have support for vsync, making it hard to have those ultra smooth animations

2) **No multithreading in the UI**. I understand the reasoning and I hear there was a model for multithreading in the UI that was scrapped due to complexity/deadlines. The current model however is very limiting IMO. Currently you can't have one animation running and start doing anything else UI intensive without the animation stuttering. Even if re-architecturing WPF to be multithreaded would be beyond their scope they should try and make animations multithreaded somehow. Currently the only way around this is using and layering windows running on different threads, and that gets old fast.

3) **No native WPF  webbrowser control** Sure you can use the windows forms webcontrol but it's not a native WPF control that you can manipulate and the performance is still pretty bad. Compare that with the Chromium browser for WPF which is awesomely fast. Hopefully they'll get around to integrating IE9 properly

4) **Text quality**,  With WPF 4.0 they improved text quality a lot, especially for small text. However I still see many WPF apps with suboptimal textrendering. It's especially noticeably  for medium to large text. I'm not saying it's bad it's not just great either. If they could take text quality with rendering on par with Photoshop (maybe per configuration so you could sacrifice performance for quality where needed )  it would really put WPF over the edge and allow us to build some great looking applications.

5) **The template system** This is probably a pet peeve and I totally agree with the design thinking around templating controls. Separating functionality from design is great. However I usually find the way it's currently done is pretty messy and subclassing custom controls to change some aspect and knowing what control to change/modify isn't exactly easy. Perhaps they could make it a bit easier

6) **Overally performance**. WPF is pretty fast but it's not lighting fast in some instances. If the different panels, flowdocument etc could be tweaked to be more instaneous it would be great for user experience. Probably another area that would benefit for taking advantage of multiple cores in the architecture.

Comment: Don't agree with #5, interested for an expansion on "...pretty messy and subclassing custom controls to change some aspect and knowing what control to change/modify isn't exactly easy..."

Comment: It's mainly when you have to replicate the whole tree rather than just being able to tweak the aspect of your control you want. I'm not sure what the solution is here, maybe if you could more easily could change classes programmatically with intellisense etc it would be easier to make small tweaks to existing controls.